# Difference between Inner join and Column Join

Tags: sql

Joining of two table by inner join and by two same columns gives us same response.

**Perform by Inner Join**

```
select N.newsno , N.newsArticleno , E.empid , E.empsal 
  from News N  inner join  tblEmployee E on  (E.empid  = N.newsno);
```

**perform by same Column Joins**

```
select  N.newsno , N.newsArticleno , E.empid , E.empsal 
   from News N , tblEmployee E 
  where (E.empid  = N.newsno);
```

***Output of Both tables are  Same.***

So please explain me what are differences between this queries and how it can use in different cases 
Thanks in Advance!!!.....

Comment: why tagged c#, java, android, php?

Comment: One uses the correct, explicit `JOIN` syntax.   The other uses an archaic syntax that should be obsoleted.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I already gave you a Teradata use-case where join on table functions does not support ANSI JOIN syntax. Yesterday I have answered a SO question about Oracle's Materialized Views which apparently also do not support ANSI JOIN syntax. So although I would recommend to use ANSI JOIN wherever possible, old school joins are still here.

Answer (score 2):

Logically these queries are identical.

The 2nd query uses old syntax.

The 1st query uses a syntax that became a standard in 1992.
It support not only INNER JOIN but also other types of join such as LEFT JOIN and FULL JOIN that before that were implemented differently by each provider or were not implemented at all.

My recommendation is to use the ANSI/ISO standard wherever you can.

- It is human readable
- It supports more possibilities
- It is more clean, separating between join conditions and filter conditions
- It protects you from forgetting putting join conditions

And as same as the old syntax, it is supported by the majority of the providers if not all of them.

Comment: Also `NATURAL JOIN` and `UNION JOIN` (though the latter I've not seen in the wild). Speaking of dropping the older version of things, the Standard became ISO in 1987, not sure why we are still using the older 'ANSI' moniker!

Comment: @onedaywhen I deliberately omitted NATURAL JOIN and RIGHT JOIN since I don't want to see them in use :-) I also omitted LEFT SEMI JOIN since it is still not common and AFAIK only HQL (Hive and its derivatives) supports it

Answer (score 0):

To join in 8i, just use a where clause:

```
select *  from emp, dept where emp.deptno = dept.deptno;
```

In 9i and up, you could

```
select ename, dname, emp.deptno, dept.deptno from SCOTT.EMP inner join     SCOTT.DEPT on emp.deptno = dept.deptno
```

Comment: @jarlh Oracle verisons

Answer (score 0):

Your queries enumerate the join syntax going backwards in time. However, you missed the more modern version: `NATURAL JOIN`:

```
WITH N AS ( SELECT newsno AS empid, newsArticleno FROM News ),
     E AS ( SELECT empid, empsal FROM tblEmployee )
SELECT *
  FROM N NATURAL JOIN E;
```

The problem is older syntax is never removed from the SQL Standard and SQL has ended up with many semantically equivalent ways of expressing the same query. Also vendors are generally slow in adopting new syntax (e.g. SQL Server still doesn't have `NATURAL JOIN`); long time users find it hard to move on from their favorite ways of writing code (e.g. you hear talk of 'dangerous' syntax). The reality is, there are numerous coding styles out in the wild to become familiar with.

Comment: NATURAL JOIN seems like  a cool syntax that simplifies the code significantly **BUT** think on production scenario where one day a column is being added or renamed and suddenly all the code is "broken", returning wrong results. On top of that, it is a good practice to add column as "record_create_ts" and "record_update_ts"  to every table, which makes NATURAL JOIN useless.

Comment: `NATURAL JOIN` is a bug waiting to happen.  It *never* should have been added to the standard.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: already covered this, "you hear talk of 'dangerous' syntax" lol.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz: see how my code defends against such nonsense scenarios? :)

Comment: @onedaywhen, LOL :-), well protected, unnecessarily complicated, and in case of  10th to 1000ds of columns, then good luck with "Guess which columns are being joined?" :-)